# find latitude & longitude of saved marker in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers

I have circle marker

```
var myMarker = L.circleMarker(stuSplit, 
    { title: 'unselected' })
        .bindLabel("Name: " + students[i][j][0] 
                   + " ReachTime: " + students[i][j][2]);
```

Now I want to find latitude & Longitude this myMarker.

I was trying `myMarker.getLatLng()` but it is not working.

Comment: it is my point where i am placing this circle marker

Comment: How do you fill it? For my guess woud be that it is empty.

Comment: no, it is not empty. It has LatLng(55.4411764, 11.7928708);

Comment: I tried your example. `bindLabel` is not a function.

Comment: it is plugin which I am using

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem does not lie in getLatLng(). This works fine:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([55.4411764, 11.7928708], 13);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var stuSplit = L.latLng(55.4411764, 11.7928708);
var myMarker = L.circleMarker(stuSplit, 
    { title: 'unselected' })
        .addTo(map);
alert(myMarker.getLatLng());
```

See a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pX2xn/2/

Comment: bindLabel is plugin which I am using

Comment: Understood. Updated answer. That leaves the question what we are doing different then, cause it works fine for me.

Answer (score 8):

So you can

```
$("#One").click(function(){
    var curPos = myMarker.getLatLng();
    alert(curPos.lng + " : " + curPos.lat);
});
```

this in more detail.

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pX2xn/16/).